# Invalid Escape Sequence replacing img and iframe tags

Tags: regex, jsp

I'm using a replaceAll() function to strip out HTML iFrame and img tags from my string, but I'm getting a JSP error and I'm not sure why. I tested out both regex expressions on a regex tester and they both seem to pass for any `<iframe></iframe>` or `<img src="" >` tags I put in.

```
<%
  String content = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("content").toString().replaceAll("<iframe>[^\"]*<\/iframe>", " ").replaceAll("<img[^>]*\\>", " ");
  pageContext.setAttribute("content", content);
%>
```

Here's the error:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

I'm very new to regex so I'm having a hard time finding a solution for this that works. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use a parser instead.

Comment: Sounds like replaceAll doesn't like you escaping `/`. Try `.replaceAll("<iframe>[^\"]*</iframe>", " ")` instead.

Comment: @Gerrit0 Yup seems like it, that fixed the issue and everything is replacing properly now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with replace all, Trying to use:

```
replaceAll
```

On any of the 8 characters/symbols in JAVA/JSP will trigger error.

```
* ( ) + { [ ? \
```

Instead use

```
contains
```

To handle/check for the 8 characters/symbols before calling replaceAll or use regex pattern specified in the resource below.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Cheers.

Comment: From <iframe>[^\"]*<\/iframe> to <iframe>[^\"]*</iframe> the problem is the 8th character I mentioned above \